# Running python and python3 in Command Prompt does not use right Python install

Tags: python, environment-variables

I just installed Python 3.8.5 with the executable from the Python website (I am using Windows). Then, when running `python3 example.py`, which uses tkinter, it returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tkinter
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'
```

When I run `python3 --version` in Command Prompt, though, it outputs `Python 3.8.0b1`. Also, when I type something invalid after `python` or `python3`, like `python foo`, it outputs `C:\Users\User\Downloads\depot_tools\bootstrap-3_8_0b1_chromium_1_bin\python\bin\python.exe: can't open file 'foo': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`. I assume all this must be happening because it is using the Python install from the Chromium depot_tools, which I must have installed at some point.

I have removed `C:\Users\User\Downloads\depot_tools` from both the User and System environment variables and added `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\` to both, to no success. Deleting the depot_tools folder also doesn't work, outputting nothing when running `python` or `python3`. I know there is nothing wrong with the Python 3.8.5 install because running `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe example.py` runs the program as intended.

How do I change the environment variables to make running `python` or `python3` use my Python 3.8.5 install?

Comment: On Windows, you can change the default that the `py` command will pick by setting the environment variable `PY_PYTHON` to the version you want.

Comment: @martineau This worked great. If you put this as an answer I will gladly accept it.

Comment: Too late now, but thanks for the offer. It's in the documentation for [Using Python on Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html?highlight=py_python#using-python-on-windows) in the [Customizing default Python versions](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html?highlight=py_python#customizing-default-python-versions) section.